# En modo debug todo va correcto, pero al ejecutarlo falla

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando realizar una comprobación de extensión y estructura de archivos (que contengan una cabecera con unos nombres determinados y que tengan extensión .csv). El código es el siguiente:

```
function sePuedeEnviarArchivo(){
let nombreArchivo = $('file').value;
let boton = $('bSubirDoc');

if(nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") && esArchivoConDatos( $('file')) ){
    if(leerFichero($('file'))){
    boton.disabled = false;
    boton.style.visibility = "visible";
    alert("Archivo con extensión y formato correctos para enviar");
    }else{
        boton.disabled = true
        boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    alert("Archivo con formato incorrecto");
    }
}


if(null == nombreArchivo ||  nombreArchivo.length < 1){
    alert("Debe incluir un archivo, con extensión csv.");
    boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    
    
    return false;
} 

if(!nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv")){

    alert("No puede subir archivos con esa extensión. La extensión debe ser csv");
    
    boton.style.visibility = "hidden";

    

    
} 
if(nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") && !esArchivoConDatos( $('file'))){
    
    boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    //boton.disabled = true;

    alert("Archivo vacío");

}
```

}

function aviso(){
let nombreArchivo =  $('file').value;

```
if(nombreArchivo.length < 1 || !nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") ){
        
    alert("Debe incluir un archivo con extensión CSV y el formato adecuado");
    
}
```

}

function esArchivoConDatos(file){

```
var resultado = true;

let archivoIntroducido = file.files[0];


if(archivoIntroducido.size <= 2){
    
    resultado = false;
}

return resultado;
```

}

function leerFichero(file){

```
const DNI = "DNI";
const RDO_EVALUACION = "RDO.EVALUACION";

var resultadoLectura = true

 const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function() {
    alert("Se ha cargado el archivo");
    
    }; 
reader.readAsText(file.files[0]);
var resultadoArchivo = new String(reader.result);


var arregloResultado = resultadoArchivo.split(";");
if(!arregloResultado[0].startsWith(DNI) || !arregloResultado[1].startsWith(RDO_EVALUACION)) {
    resultadoLectura = false;
} 
console.log(reader.result);
```

return resultadoLectura;
}
Se llama en:

```
    <br><input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="caja" style="height: 25px;"  accept=".csv"  onchange="sePuedeEnviarArchivo()" />
```

No me produce ningún error, y al debuggear, haciendo las pruebas correspondientes con distintos archivos, funciona bien. El problema viene al ejecutarlo en modo "normal", ya que me trata los archivos correctos como incorrectos. ¿A alguien le ha pasado algo parecido? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: A que te refieres con "modo normal" ?

Comment: Hola de nuevo, Yussef. Me refiero a ejecutar el programa como lo haría cualquier usuario. Dándole al botón de insertar. Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado tu código, porque básicamente no lo entiendo, pero entiendo lo que quieres hacer:

Básicamente quieres 2 tipos de validaciones

- Validar la extensión del archivo
- Validar el contenido del archivo

Para esto creamos ambas funciones `validarNombre` y `validarContenido` respectivamente.

Luego necesitamos 2 funciones que hagan algo en pantalla para alertar de la validación (habilitar o deshabilitar un boton, cambiar color, mensaje, etc). Las llamaremos

- `permitirEnviar`
- `bloquearEnviar`

Y el flujo es el siguiente:

1. Se selecciona un archivo y se gatilla un evento donde:
2. Primero se valida el nombre del archivo, y solo si es correcto
3. Se abre el archivo y se valida su contenido

```js
function validarNombre(nombre){
  if(nombre==null || nombre.length<=4 || !nombre.endsWith(".csv"))
  {
    return "Debe incluir un archivo, con extensión csv.";
  }
  return true;
}

function validarContenido(content){

   const DNI = "DNI";
   const RDO_EVALUACION = "RDO.EVALUACION";
   let cont = content.split(";");
   if(content.length==0 || cont.length<2){

      return "El archivo está vacio";
   }
   if(!cont[0].startsWith(DNI) || !cont[1].startsWith(RDO_EVALUACION)) {

    return "El archivo no tiene el formato adecuado";
   }

   return true;
}

function permitirEnviar(){
  document.getElementById("bSubirDoc").disabled = false;
  console.log("todo OK");
}

function bloquearEnviar(mensaje){
  document.getElementById("bSubirDoc").disabled = true;
  console.log(mensaje);
}

function leerFichero(input){
  if(input.files.lenght==0){ //validar si existe el archivo
     bloquearEnviar("No ha seleccionado archivo");
  }
  
  let validName = validarNombre(input.value);
  if(validName !== true) { //valida la extensión del archivo
     bloquearEnviar(validName);
  }
  
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
     let validContent = validarContenido(reader.result);
     
     if(validContent===true){//valida el contenido
       permitirEnviar();
     }
     else{
       bloquearEnviar(validContent);
     }
  }
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
}
```

```html
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="caja" style="height: 25px;"  accept=".csv"  onchange="leerFichero(this)" />

<button id="bSubirDoc" disabled>Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, Yussef.